# problem in typing Promise that returns a Union of types

Tags: typescript

(using TypeScript 4.6.3)

I have the following SSCCE code that represents the outcome of a login operation. For some reason unrelated to this question, I want to handle the case of bad password under a `resolve` branch:

Typescript Playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAMg9gcwJYgPJgC4GM4WFAbwGUBVAYTIFEiiAaKAMQEEBJGAXwFgAoHjATwAO%20eMhAAlYAGcwAGwxSoAXkI8o6qHEw48ALliIU6bLmAA6UhWpE1G4QCcpcEAH0QAQz1QpGeygQ87FAAPqrcGprapvqiRlF4ZsxsgTyp3ABmYCBYGEjOULKGIAAUAJT6AAr2uEhSwAA8sRLScgoAfGG2OCA%20UILVELXAlQNDjUWSMvJSHSogwADuUFU1dcVQxfbScLIAbsD0WwBWwDmlyh0EaRF1GAAqSHhaGMVlSm1X4RFQ3b32AIzKQjPHTDAxiYygizkKg0egOJyuDxeABEACk4AALEAo9gAblsEV%20GCg9gATECCCDouC4iYEkkOATeF8Ikh0hsALLuDCYsz2dwgAAmuDKUHqKgADGYAKylQnfLYYMD2ECk7Z7YCbf6lZnfKDAWR1BURJUqtVbJyazZk3UmqAK9j0ADMkrddq%207A96jNqr6ozqzLSXBZPCAA).

```
enum LoginOutcome {SUCCESS, FAIL}

type LoginResults = {
    outcome: LoginOutcome.SUCCESS
    person_name: string
} | {
    outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL
}


function login(): Promise<LoginResults> {
  const promise: Promise<LoginResults> = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(()=>{
      const r1 = {outcome: LoginOutcome.SUCCESS, person_name: "John"};
      const r2 = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL};

      if (Math.random() <= 0.5)
         return resolve(r1);
      else
        return resolve(r2); // TS complains: Type 'LoginOutcome' is not assignable to type 'LoginOutcome.FAIL'.(2345)
      
    }, 3000);
  });
  return promise;
}
```

The above code does not typecheck as indicated in the comment.
I don't understand why.
Also, I have discovered that if I change the line:

```
const r2 = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL};
```

to:

```
const r2: LoginResults = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL};
```

… then the code typechecks. This makes no sense at all as TS should have been able to infer that `{outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL}` is a valid instance of type `LoginResults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way that TypeScript infers data in non-`as const` expressions.  When you have literal values such as enum members or strings or numbers, it will simply resolve to the generic enum type / `string` / `number`.  Therefore, the following assignment:

```
const r2 = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL};
```

Actually resolves to this type:

```
declare const r2: { outcome: LoginOutcome }; // not specifically `LoginOutcome.FAIL`
```

When you type `r2` to `LoginResults`, it is forced to see if it matches the literals because the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) uses literals for the values.  Therefore, it can correctly type check as you expect it to.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that using `const r2 = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL} as const` is preferable to `const r2: LoginOutcome = {outcome: LoginOutcome.FAIL}` ?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus You couldn't do `as const` like in your example because that would make the `outcome` property readonly which would make the object not assignable to the mutable type signature of `LoginOutcome`.  You would need to do `{ outcome: LoginOutcome.SUCCESS as const }` to only make the value the literal.  Personally, I'd rather just include the `LoginOutcome` type though because it makes more sense to me.